# If MathJax renders pure unicode, store that directly instead of re-rendering formulae

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

Take e.g. `$\delta A$`, which is just δA in some other font. Why should it be rendered over and over again when it is sufficient to store the unicode text together with some `<ThisIsAFormulaSoUseAMathFont>`?

Comment: I think the re-rendering has better aesthetics.

Comment: @yayu but performance?

Comment: It also makes editing easier. Unless you mean to have a stored "original" version and a cached "rendered" version. But that sort of defeats the whole purpose of MathJax.